# Web service server issue

Tags: java, webservice-client

When I use web service client call server in websphere

Server system log as below

anyone knows how to fix this?

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.

Comment: This question lacks details. Please provide more system logs (more lines) and other information if any.

Answer (score 1):

This issue reported as a bug please check [this link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5843) for more details.

Comment: Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: No, in my opinion better way is choosing another version or web server.

Comment: I fought with this issue couple days, hard to change web service at company

Comment: finally,I build the project in other colleague’s local ,and works.thanks anyway.